# How to limit the minimum size of a windows form in visual studio?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I am creating a simple Windows form application using Visual C#.

The form is can re-sized by the user (by click and drag). But, I don't want the user to decrease the dimensions of the form beyond a certain limit. How can I set the limits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to your form in VS and press <kbd>F4</kbd> to get to the properties of the form and look for the MinimumSize property:

[image]

To set the size from code use:

```
this.MinimumSize = new Size(100, 100);
```

Note that this does not prevent minimising/maximising the form! If you want to prevent this, then set the `MaximizeBox` property to `false`.

Comment: In MSVS 2015, the default minimum width is too small, but when I put in a bigger number it reverts to the previous value as soon as I hit enter or tab to another property. Why is that?

Comment: @KevinMiller Are you changing only the width field, or the combined **width; height** field (if you put only one number into the combined field, it is not accepted)? What number are you putting in? Is your code under source control?

Comment: I expanded the Minimum Size property and changed the width value from 0 to 1229, but when I tab out it changes to 1159. I can make it smaller than 1159, but larger values revert. I am using GIT, but it changes immediately, not after a pull if I understand your point. The form has a TableLayoutPanel which contains a TabControl and a StatusStrip and rows and columns. I think the problem may be the interaction of the sizes of these elements inside elements but I haven't been able to figure it out. The form was developed by someone else several years ago.

Comment: @KevinMiller it is because of the TableLayoutPanel - it has a fixed (or max) size set and/or AutoSize property set to true and thus all children controls are truncated to this value. I would suggest to inspect the TableLayoutPanel and check all (layout)control hierarchies to identify the problem.

Comment: .@pasty - That was it. There was an empty element with a fixed size used to simulate align right on a label. I removed the element and set the container to alignRight.

Answer (score 0):

In the WinForm properties there is minimum size property
see here 
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.minimumsize(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.minimumsize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To change it on run-time:

```
int width, height;
this.MinimumSize = new Size(width, height);
```